# Reduced ducted air flow with heat pump

Tags: hvac, ducts, heat-pump

This post is part of the research I did before installing a heat pump recently, which may help add context: [Gas furnace switch to heat pump installation?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/262586/107574)

The heat pump I got installed is flexx36hp230v1ao: [Gree Flexx](https://www.greecomfort.com/our-products/flexx/)

After having this heat pump now for ~1 month, one thing I'm noticing is that the air flow coming out of the ducts feels dramatically reduced. On duct outlets closer to the HVAC stack there's a trickle of air, but further away the vent is basically just a warm spot on the wall.

When the gas furnace is on, the air flow is fine. I called the HVAC company that installed the heat pump and they said that air moves slower over the coils for a heat pump compared to a furnace, so the air flow is reduced.

Does this all sound correct? Did the HVAC company sell me a garbage heat pump? Even though this heat pump is rated down to -22F, I find it doesn't keep up when the outside temperature is below 20F, which is very disappointing, and I wonder if that's related to the reduced airflow.

Comment: I would suggest calling (yes, by voice) the maker of your heat pump and explain your issues. They have the power to inspire your dealer to do better if they want to **stay** a dealer, if you can get them to grasp that either the system was misrepresented or it's not installed correctly to perform as represented.